# css div with auto margins does not scale smaller

Tags: html, css

i have a div which needs to be horizontal-centered and can scale smaller than its width.

I use this code to center the div, but it doesn't work with scaling. the div wont scale smaller then its max-width. This is true for both Firefox and IE.

```
/* CSS doesnt work in Firefox and IE */
.center
{
    max-width: 940px;
    height: inherit;

    background-image: url(../img/koeien%20liggen.JPG);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* HTML */
<div class="headerWrapper">
    <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

How do i center a div horizontally and let it scale smaller when resizing the browser in IE, Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Try `width: 100%;`

Comment: margin:0 auto; I do not understand the issue though

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the center div to scale you can't use a max width but instead use a percentage width, so there are always borders on either side. Use media queries to make the width 100%, and thus remove the borders, at any viewport width you choose. Also remember there's no such thing as "height: inherit". CSS doesn't compare object but instead affects the equally. You can say "height: auto", though.

```css
.center
{
    max-width: 50%;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url(../img/koeien%20liggen.JPG);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.headerWrapper {
  background: aqua;
  }
```

```html
<div class="headerWrapper">
    <div class="center">THING</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with setting % width to the div and it will resize on window resize.

The other ugly way is to resize it dynamically with js on window resize (it will give you the advantage of defining your own step for resizing)